# Keras VAE example on non-image/text data

Tags: keras, autoencoder

Im trying to adapt the VAE example given here https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html to a non-image/text data.

What i don't understand, first off, is the 'args' in below function :

```
def sampling(args):
    z_mean, z_log_sigma = args
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(batch_size, latent_dim),
                          mean=0., std=epsilon_std)
    return z_mean + K.exp(z_log_sigma) * epsilon
```

also, how to randomly sample some points from 
         z = Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(latent_dim,))([z_mean,z_log_sigma])

to feed into the decoder network for generating new data??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What i don't understand, first off, is the 'args' in below function :

args is a tuple that contains two tensors (z_mean, z_log_sigma). These tensors are the output of the encoder split in half. i.e. the output of the decoder is interpreted to be the mean and log variance of a normal distribution.

> how to randomly sample some points from z = Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(latent_dim,))([z_mean,z_log_sigma])

That is what `sampling` does. It samples a tensor of shape `(batch_size, latent_dim)` from a normal distribution and then scales it by adding mean and multiplying by `exp(log_sigma)` per each latent_dim.

i.e. suppose that latent_dim is 2 for the sake of example, then the random values epsilon sampled from the normal distribution are processed such that `sampled[0] = (random_values[:, 0] + z_mean[0]) * exp(z_log_sigmal[0])` and the same for column 1.

With VAE, the output of the encoder is interpreted as parameters for a Gaussian distribution. The parameters are then used by the sampling function to generate random values for those distributions by transforming the output of a normal distribution sampling process.

Comment: So zmean and zlogvar are inputs to sampling; and to get some random latent dimension vectors, for generating novel (new data points), i'll have to just change the batch_size of Sampling function to e.g 200 if i wanna generate 200 new latent vectors as input to decorder?

Comment: No. You have to change the latent_dims size to get different latent dimensions. batch_size controls the number of samples that are used for each SGD mini batch. I'd recommend you leave it as default until you start playing with the learning rate of the model.